# tools for creating user-friendly command-line prompt?

Tags: c++, bash, command-prompt, user-friendly

I notice that some programs (e.g. `sqlite`, `mysql` client) provide a command-line prompt that is very similar in capabilities to the `bash`'s, including:

- **line editing** with left and right arrows, delete, insert, ^K, etc.
- **history browsing** with up and down arrows
- ^R for **reverse i-search** in command history

which make me think that they are using the same toolset for this.

I'd like to create a prompt with similar capabilities in my program, which tools can I use? I prefer it to have the same functionality as in `bash`, so that the users would be familiar with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of these use the [GNU readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) library

Comment: seems like what I was looking for, thanks! I wander how they deal with the GPL in MySql though, MySql not being a free software anymore...

Comment: The commercial version of MySQL doesn't link against readline, but BSD-licensed libedit.

Comment: BTW: are you familiar with any C++ wrapper for readline? Are they good?

Comment: @mkb: funny, I just saw a "proof" of that: while playing with both readline and libedit, I noticed that one does not display ^D when pressed and the second does. Now, switching from the community version of mysql to the commercial one, I see exactly this behavior... :)